# Stick TextView on the top once it is scrolled to the top of the visible area

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I'm working on this `nestedscrollview` for a while now. It contains a single child `RelativeLayout`. Here's the pseudo code.

```
<NestedScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout>
         <TextView />  //text A
         <CalendaerView />
         <TextView /> //id = date_string //shows a date string
         <RecyclerView /> //list of events
    <RelativeLayout>
</NestedScrollView>
```

The idea is while performing a scroll downwards, the entire view should scroll as normal, but once the date string `TextView` reaches top of the visible area, it has to stay on the top for further scroll down. However, when it is scrolled upwards, I should be able to see `CalendarView` and text A.

I tried scroll listener for `nestedscrollview` and created another `textview` outside `nestedscrollview` and changed the `visibility`.

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <TextView /> //to mimic date string
  <NestedScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout>
       <TextView />  //text A
       <CalendaerView />
       <TextView /> //id = date_string //shows a date string
       <RecyclerView /> //list of events
   <RelativeLayout>
  </NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the scroll listener logic

```
public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
      if (isDone && scrollY < oldScrollY) {
          //scroll up
          int firstVisibleItem = ((LinearLayoutManager) mRecycler.getLayoutManager())
                        .findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                if(0 == firstVisibleItem) {
                    textA.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    calendarView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    dateString.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    dateStringCopy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            if (scrollY > oldScrollY) {
                //scroll down
                int dateTop = dateString.getTop();
                //check if datestring reaches the top of screen
                if(0 >= dateTop - scrollY) {
                    isDone = false;
                    textA.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    calendarView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    dateString.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    dateStringCopy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            isDone = true;
                        }
                    }, 50);
                }
            }
        }
```

In reality, the experience is not very smooth as it involves changing visibility of views. Has anyone got any better way to solve this?

Comment: Hope [this](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I was looking to understand its working without third party library. But yeah, here we go. I shall modify it to my use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple Github library project.

https://github.com/amarjain07/StickyScrollView

[image]